# Custom user-driven reports on a known schema

Tags: sql, reporting

There's an upcoming project at work to fill a requirement that end-users be able to generate custom reports off their data in within our fixed/known-schema relational database.

The interface needs to be very user friendly and so transposing all of t-sql's language concepts into a graphical paradigm is far too complex for both the project team and the end user.

What research or products, open-source or otherwise, exist around satisfying this of business need?  I'm aware of general Business Analytic tools but this is more specific and I'm trying to understand the problem domain better rather than trying to reverse engineer it from vendor marketing materials.

I assume the research would be in the form of a some encoding of the schema that specifies which joins and tables are allowed, which fields are available, then then a method for allowing the user to select one particular valid combination among the possible many, generate the query, and display the results.

Brainstorming - feature support in order of complexity: SELECT, WHERE filters, FULL JOIN, LEFT JOIN, sorting, paging, grouping, aggregation, HAVING filter.

My backup plan is to just dumb it down to pre-written SQL Views (with JOINs built-in) with the ability to display available columns with custom row-wise filtering.  Paging and sorting is doable.  By itself, this doesn't allow for grouping, aggregate functions, HAVING filters, or other inter-row analysis.

Comment: Which technologies are you using?  Sql Server has a built-in report designer that can be exposed to the end user.  Tools like ActiveReport allows you to do something similar.. a quick search on Google reveals many ad hoc reporting tools..

Comment: Microsoft web app technologies.  Report server is not webby enough here.

Comment: If this is an internal application, you can use the SSRS report builder (a clickonce win forms app).. but that can be a bear to set up..

Comment: @Bobby D - no, it's customer-facing.  But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow-up to @Dems post (comment box wasn't bit enough :) )..

Agreed on most counts..  If your data is mostly analytic, then you might want to look into a tool like [PowerPivot](http://www.powerpivot.com/).  In this case, you can write a general query then allow the users to derive reports based on the result set in a familiar tool (Excel).

At the core of every ad hoc reporting engine, you will find a few common themes:

**Metadata**
There will be some way of describing the schema such that the model may be easily consumed by the user.  Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) requires you to build a metadata model in order to use the report builder.  When using PowerPivot, you can alias column names to make them more readable, but in the end, you are simply providing a flat dataset and allowing the user to build the joins/relationships.

**Query Builder**
Once the metadata has been manipulated by the user, an intermediary system must be in place to convert the conceptual report into an actual query.  Many tools are measured based on the complexity of the Sql that they produce as this can greatly affect performance.  One way to get around this is to create views that the reporting engine may build queries against.  One of the best open source examples of this that I have seen is the engine that backs Hibernate/NHibernate (look into how the various `Dialects` are used when building queries).

**Rendering Engine**
In my experience building a rendering engine is not a road you want to go down.  There are many device-specific concerns as well as look & feel problems (i.e. how do you plan on representing cascading joins/relationships?).  Every rendering engine has it's own quirks (PowerPivot uses Excel, SSRS has a service that builds the raw result and return it to the consuming application) that must be accounted for, so be careful how you choose.

Earlier I mentioned that I agreed on *most counts*.  I would not recommend encouraging your users to learn Sql or allowing them to pass-through Sql to the underlying data-store.  This opens the door to malicious code being written and can become a security nightmare.  Not to mention that most business users think in terms of flat tables, not hierarchical sets.

Figure out what your users are comfortable with and try to fit your solution to that domain.  I have often found that for sophisticated business users something like PowerPivot is perfect.  For more day-to-day end users, having "canned" reports that might be modified by the end user via a simple user interface that allows them to modify restrictions/groupings/sorting is more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed summary of the inner workings of these technologies.  This is helpful in continuing to Google.  Too bad PivotTable isn't web-based, but it may be a good discovery tool to work with management and users on what their real requirements are.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options out there, but the best of them cost money.

I really like QlikView as an easy to use report designed for semi-technical people.  If your user base is more technically minded it may be a bit restrictive, but if your user base have no logical thought capabilities, it's too complicated.  That's the biggest trap I see you falling in to...
- No, I want more than that!
- No, that's too complicated for me!
- At the same time...

If you were to build your own tool-set internally, you'd probably be best sticking with OLAP cubes.  Let people slice and dice the data as they like, but with all the relationships pre-defined.  Do it right and you can just point an Excel Pivot Table at the OLAP Cube and let them play...

The next up, as Bobby D says, could be SQL Server Reporting Services, or something similar.

But if your users end up wanting absolute flexibility, the tool they need is SQL itself.  Unfortunately, all tools follow the same trend: The more flexible and powerful, the more time you need to spend learning/training.

Comment: Another great answer!  Thanks.  Certainly requirements are key here.  They don't know what they want yet.  They just want to build a v1 and expand, but I think this is the type of problem where the original direction locks you in pretty tightly regarding future expansion.